# Column Names in Pandas (Python)

Tags: python, pandas

Python : Pandas : Data Frame : Column Names

I have large number of columns and column names are also very large. I would like to see few columns and rows but view becoming restricted to size of column names. How can I temporarily see dataframe in Python without column names (just display data )

Comment: `df.head().values` for a few rows. or `df.loc[row_labels, column_labels].values` for specific rows / columns.

Answer (score 2):

Convert DataFrame to numpy array:

```
print (df.values)
```

But maybe here is possible select values of columns by positions first by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
print (df.iloc[:, 5:8].values)
```

**Sample**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(3,10)))
print (df)
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  8  4  9  1  3  7  6  3  0  3
1  3  2  6  8  9  3  7  5  7  4
2  0  0  7  5  7  3  9  3  9  3

print (df.iloc[:, 5:8])
   5  6  7
0  7  6  3
1  3  7  5
2  3  9  3

print (df.iloc[:, 5:8].values)
[[7 6 3]
 [3 7 5]
 [3 9 3]]
```